# HTML5 void elements' ending / is optional, but is it preferable?

Tags: html, tags, coding-style, w3c

HTML5 allows either `<br>` or `<br/>`. Does the W3C specification or any other authority state whether one is preferable over the other? Is there a good reason (or reasons) to use one over the other if adherence to XHTML is irrelevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML5 compliant browsers, this makes no difference. I think you would have difficulty citing any resource which preferred `<br />` over `<br>`, slash-trailing image tags, or even closing `<path>` elements. It is most likely preferable not to have the trailing slash simply because the document takes just that much longer to fetch from the webserver and for the HTML interpreter to serialize (as minuscule a time differential as this actually provides). In addition, all HTML5 compliant browsers strip these characters in runtime, which is evident when you call `outerHTML` on an HtmlElement.

EDIT: I also think that if there was any difference or adherance to a standard to preserve, it would be reflected on the w3c page: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/br

However, I feel as though it is worth mentioning that browsers that are not compliant with HTML5 standards (mostly earlier, unsupported versions of IE) demand a trailing slash to render the element.

Comment: Good point about older browsers requiring a trailing slash. I should've stated in my question that the question was meant for modern browsers only.

Comment: Of course, I saw the HTML and HTML5 tags and decided it was worth mentioning.

Comment: It DOES make a difference and there is no preference involved! The closing slash is NOT specified for such tags and void elements only states that it can be used but browsers are to ignored it. An ignored property can only mean that, eventually, such things will be removed from the specification. Also, older browsers do NOT require the trailing slash cause there is not such thing in HTML.

Answer (score -1):

HTML is not XML.

In HTML, `/` is nonsense, for instance:

```
<script type="text/javascript" />
//This line is in Javascript, not HTML
alert('Hello');
</script>
```

I don't think `/` is useful at all

Comment: I was referring to void elements, not elements with content in them.

Comment: But anyway, though it is void element or not, `/` is nonsense @at.

Comment: So explain why `<svg><script type="text/javascript" >alert('Hello');</script></svg>` display the hello alert while `<svg><script type="text/javascript" />alert('Hello');</script></svg>` does not.

Comment: @Alohci because svg file is an xml file (there's no different between them), you can change your file extension `.svg` to `.xml`.

Comment: What I posted are fragments of HTML5. Nothing to do with files or extensions.

Comment: @Alohci HTML (with `.html` extension) is not XML, but SVG is technically an XML. Also, I think you do not post `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, right? If you remove it (`xmlns`), you will see the alert dialog.

Comment: OK. See this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/99cnnbn9/ JSFiddle is only for HTML. In HTML, the namespace assignment (xmlns) has no effect because the HTML parser knows how to deal with the `<svg>` element,

Comment: @Alohci OK. `<svg>` element need no `xmlns` in HTML. However, anyway, SVG is an XML, and `/` makes sense in XML but not HTML